# "Project.exe has triggered a breakpoint" after p_array++; in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, pointers

So I tried to learn pointers again and when I entered a number Visual Studio gave me an error.
Here's the source:

```
// Includes
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

// Variables
int amount;

// Main function
int main()
{
    cout << "How many numbers should be in this array: ";
    cin >> amount;
    int *p_array;
    p_array = new int[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        cout << (int)p_array << endl;
        p_array++;
    }
    delete[] p_array;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I know that there's a problem with `p_array++;`.

Also when I tried to compile this in Code::Blocks it worked perfectly (I deleted `#include "stadfx.h"` and changed `_getch();` to `getch();` when compiling it in codeblocks).

P.S. I'm new to C++ :P

Comment: The problem is in `delete[] p_array;` The reason for the bug is `p_array` no longer points to the address that was allocated using new because you incremented it in the loop.

Comment: @drescherjm Thank you! I fixed it using your tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by doing this:

```
// Includes
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

// Variables
int amount;
int *pointer;

// Main function
int main()
{
    cout << "How many numbers should be in this array: ";
    cin >> amount;
    int *p_array;
    p_array = new int[amount];
    pointer = p_array;
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        cout << (int)p_array << endl;
        p_array++;
    }
    p_array = pointer;
    delete[] p_array;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}﻿
```

I made a pointer with name `pointer` and stored original address of `p_array` then before `delete[] p_array;` i assigned address stored in `pointer` to `p_array`.

Thanks to drescherjm for telling me what's the problem.

I guess that noone will need this explanation but I thought to write it here.

Comment: I forgot to add, can anyone tell me what is wrong with my question? I'm asking because it received 3 downvotes and I don't know what's wrong.